# Using Ternaries to find Full Month Name (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement, short

I try to change the value by using this technique in php, but it didn't work! Unfortunately, I also don't know the name of this technique. So limitation for me to search the solution in google.

```
echo $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '01' ? "January" ||
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '02' ?  "February" ||
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '03' ?  "March" || 
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '04' ?  "April" || 
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '05' ?  "May" || 
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '06' ?  "June" || 
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '07' ?  "July" || 
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '08' ?  "August" || 
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '09' ?  "September" || 
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '10' ?  "October" || 
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '11' ?  "November" || 
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '12' ?  "December"  : "Invalid Month!";
```

Comment: switch? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Use an array map. Also, your question title: make it descriptive, not useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you wanted:

```
// $month_num is in separate variable in case $session_slct->f("theMonth") is i.e. slow operation or using external resource
$month_num = $session_slct->f("theMonth");
echo ($month_num == '01') ? "January" :
     ($month_num == '02') ?  "February" :
     ($month_num == '03') ?  "March" :
     ($month_num == '04') ?  "April" :
     ($month_num == '05') ?  "May" :
     ($month_num == '06') ?  "June" :
     ($month_num == '07') ?  "July" :
     ($month_num == '08') ?  "August" :
     ($month_num == '09') ?  "September" :
     ($month_num == '10') ?  "October" :
     ($month_num == '11') ?  "November" :
     ($month_num == '12') ?  "December"  : "Invalid Month!";
```

or even:

```
switch ($session_slct->f("theMonth")) {
    case '01': $month = "January"; break;
    case '02': $month = "February"; break;
    case '03': $month = "March"; break;
    case '04': $month = "April"; break;
    case '05': $month = "May"; break;
    case '06': $month = "June"; break;
    case '07': $month = "July"; break;
    case '08': $month = "August"; break;
    case '09': $month = "September"; break;
    case '10': $month = "October"; break;
    case '11': $month = "November"; break;
    case '12': $month = "December"; break;
    default: $month = "Invalid Month!";
}

echo $month;
```

but these are not really [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) options, you might use PhpMyCoder and efritz solutions ;)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but your solution is always go to December

Comment: i remove the ternary operation and used the switch function. It work! thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need ternaries or array maps when you have [date](http://www.php.net/date):

```
echo date('F', strtotime($month.'/1/2010'));
```

But if you insist on using ternaries, check PHP.net for the [correct syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). It should be:

```
echo $month == '01' ? 'January' :
     $month == '02' ? 'February' :
     //etc
```

Basically, `||` is the OR operator, not the colon you need to specify the alternative for the ternary.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is called a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). The typical setup is this:

```
$variable = ($someValue == "abc") ? "yes" : "no";
```

I am not sure why you are using pipes instead of the colon. Do it like so:

```
echo $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '01' ? "January" :
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '02' ?  "February" :
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '03' ?  "March" :
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '04' ?  "April" :
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '05' ?  "May" :
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '06' ?  "June" :
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '07' ?  "July" :
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '08' ?  "August" :
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '09' ?  "September" :
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '10' ?  "October" :
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '11' ?  "November" :
     $session_slct->f("theMonth") == '12' ?  "December"  :
     "Invalid Month!";
```

Comment: i try to make it as OR that's why i'm using || insted of :

Comment: The ternary operation requires both `?` and `:`, so you cannot use the or pipes in addition to the ternary operation.

Answer (score 3):

Xaerxees's answer is correct, but a *better* way would be:

```
$months = array(
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
);

if (isset($months[$session_slct->f("theMonth") - 1])) {
    echo $months[$session_slct->f("theMonth") - 1];
} else {
    echo "Invalid Month";
}
```

Or, if you prefer, you could always index them as the following, and drop the `- 1` stuff:

```
$months = array(
    '01' => 'January',
    '02' => 'February',
    '03' => 'March',
    // etc
```

Comment: This is better solution than if/case/ternary through 12 cases ;) @efritz: you want `$session_slct->f("theMonth") - 1` instead `$session_slct->f("theMonth") + 1` and it would be more readable if you use `$zero_based_month = $session_slct->f("theMonth") - 1; if (in_array($zero_based_month, $months))`

Answer (score 1):

You' trying to use the ternary operator, but you're using `||` instead of `:`.

```
$session_slct->f("theMonth") == '01' ?'January':
$session_slct->f("theMonth") == '02' /* ...
```

But you're better off using switch... case.

```
$month = 'Invalid Month!';
switch( $session_slct->f("theMonth") )
{
   case '01':
      $month = 'January';
      break;
   case '02':
      $month = 'February';
      break;
   /* ... */
}
```

The problem with using the ternary the way you are is that you are calling `$session_slct->f` *twelve times* in a row. That is far more expensive than switch, which calls it once or, if you're insistent on ternary, at least cache the variable first:

```
$month = $session_slct->f("theMonth");
echo $month == '01' ?'January':
     $month == '02' ?'February':// yada yada yada/
```

Of course there are always solutions like:

```
echo date( 'F', strtotime( '01-' . $session_slct->f("theMonth") ) );
```